# Neo4j: WHERE clause ID(node) in collection slow

Tags: neo4j

The following Cypher query is executing very slow.  The profile of it looks good - can someone point out what I am doing wrong.  It should return fast based on the time it takes to run each section.

```
PROFILE 
MATCH 
   (deal2:lDeal)   <-[tr2:PARTICIPATES_IN]- (frComp:lCompany { id:2353462}) //1944 rows
MATCH
   (inter) -[tr1:WORKED_IN | PARTICIPATES_IN]-> (deal2) //58,373
WITH 
   collect(distinct id(inter)) as interCol
MATCH 
   (article:lArticle { articleId:13194153})  -[r:WRITTEN_ABOUT] ->  (Comp1:lCompany)
MATCH 
   (Comp1) -[fr1:PARTICIPATES_IN]-> (deal1:lDeal)  //6671
MATCH 
   (deal1) <-[fr2:WORKED_IN | PARTICIPATES_IN]- (inter) //135,011
WHERE 
   id(inter) in interCol
RETURN 
   inter
```

[image]

EDIT 8/18/2014 2:41PM EST:

Tried several variations based on @jjaderberg's recommendation without any performance improvements:

VARIATION 1:

```
MATCH 
  (inter)-[:WORKED_IN|PARTICIPATES_IN]->(:lDeal)<-[:PARTICIPATES_IN]-(:lCompany {id:2353462})
WHERE 
   inter-[:WORKED_IN|PARTICIPATES_IN]->(:lDeal)<-[:PARTICIPATES_IN]-(:lCompany)<-[:WRITTEN_ABOUT]-(:lArticle {articleId:13194153})
```

VARIATION 2:

```
MATCH 
    (inter)-[:WORKED_IN|PARTICIPATES_IN]->(cDeal:lDeal)
WHERE 
    cDeal<-[:PARTICIPATES_IN]-(:lCompany {id:2353462}) 
WITH 
    inter
MATCH 
    inter-[:WORKED_IN|PARTICIPATES_IN]->(:lDeal)<-[:PARTICIPATES_IN]-(:lCompany)<-[:WRITTEN_ABOUT]-(:lArticle {articleId:13194153})
RETURN inter
```

VARIATION 3:

```
MATCH 
    (inter)-[:WORKED_IN|PARTICIPATES_IN]->(cDeal:lDeal)
WHERE 
    cDeal<-[:PARTICIPATES_IN]-(:lCompany {id:2353462}) 
WITH 
    inter
MATCH 
    inter-[:WORKED_IN|PARTICIPATES_IN]->(:lDeal)<-[:PARTICIPATES_IN]-(:lCompany)<-[:WRITTEN_ABOUT]-(:lArticle {articleId:13194153})
RETURN 
    inter
```

VARIATION 4:

```
MATCH 
    (inter)-[:WORKED_IN|PARTICIPATES_IN]->(cDeal:lDeal)
WHERE 
    cDeal<-[:PARTICIPATES_IN]-(:lCompany {id:2353462}) 
WITH 
    inter
MATCH 
    inter-[:WORKED_IN|PARTICIPATES_IN]->(aDeal:lDeal)
WHERE 
    aDeal<-[:PARTICIPATES_IN]-(:lCompany)<-[:WRITTEN_ABOUT]-(:lArticle {articleId:13194153})
RETURN 
    inter
```

Also tried @MichaelHunger's solution - it still takes too long to profile. 
Per Michael's request - here are some additional query profiles:

```
PROFILE
MATCH 
  (inter)-[:WORKED_IN|PARTICIPATES_IN]->(deal:lDeal)<-[:PARTICIPATES_IN]-  (c:lCompany {id:2353462})
USING 
   index c:lCompany(id)
RETURN 
   count(*), count(distinct inter), count(distinct deal), count(distinct c);
```

[image]
[image]

```
PROFILE
MATCH   
   inter-[:WORKED_IN|PARTICIPATES_IN]->(deal:lDeal)<-[:PARTICIPATES_IN]-(c:lCompany)<-[:WRITTEN_ABOUT]-(a:lArticle {articleId:13194153})
USING 
    INDEX a:lArticle(articleId)
RETURN 
    count(*), count(distinct inter), count(distinct deal), count(distinct a), count(distinct c);
```

[image]
[image]

The best we've been able to do so far is the following which is still slow (COST. 26370330 total db hits in 72828 ms.) :

```
MATCH 
   (comp2:lCompany {id:2353462})-[tr2:PARTICIPATES_IN]->(deal2:lDeal)<-[tr1]-(inter)-[fr2]->(deal1:lDeal)
WITH 
   DISTINCT deal1
MATCH 
   deal1<-[fr1:PARTICIPATES_IN]-(comp1:lCompany)<-[r:WRITTEN_ABOUT]-(article:lArticle)
   USING INDEX article:lArticle(articleId)
WHERE 
   article.articleId=13194153
RETURN
   DISTINCT count(comp1) as count, comp1.id ,comp1.name order by count desc, comp1.name
```

Which gives the following profile:

[image]

Comment: use `WITH distinct inter`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Working with Ted) Limiting intermediate results, the below is the best we have come up with (COST. 8,354,507 total db hits in 15,222 ms):

```
MATCH (comp2:lCompany {id:2353462})-[tr2:PARTICIPATES_IN]->(deal2:lDeal)<-[tr1]-(inter)
WITH DISTINCT inter
MATCH inter-[fr2]->(deal1:lDeal)
WITH DISTINCT deal1
MATCH deal1<-[fr1:PARTICIPATES_IN]-(comp1:lCompany)<-[r:WRITTEN_ABOUT]-(article:lArticle)
USING INDEX article:lArticle(articleId)
WHERE article.articleId=13194153
RETURN DISTINCT count(comp1) as count, comp1.id ,comp1.name order by count desc, comp1.name
```

[image: Execution Plan]

Answer (score 1):

To optimize the query I would break it into parts and optimize those. It's hard to give sure advice without understanding your domain. It might help if you share a small sample at http://console.neo4j.org. Apart from domain understanding, here are two things that I would look at.

#### 1) Filtering on paths is better than a match-match-intersection

If I understand your query you are matching two sets of nodes on two different paths from two different, individual starting points and then you return the intersection of these results. A human reconstruction of your query might be

> Please tell me about all the deals that this company participates in, or rather, about all the stakeholders that participated in or worked on those deals (only tell me about each once).
> I also have an article that writes about one or more companies and I want to know about all the stakeholders that participated in or worked on any deal that these companies participated in.
> Just kidding, I don't want to know about all of these stakeholders (union), only about those that occur on both paths (intersection)!

If this is at least a somewhat fair reconstruction, then you might consider rephrasing your query to something like

> Please tell about all the stakeholders that worked on or participated in any deals that were participated in by this Company
> if they also participated in or worked on deals that were participated in by one or more companies written about in this article.

And this might be translated back to Cypher as

```
MATCH (inter)-[:WORKED_IN|PARTICIPATES_IN]->(:lDeal)-[:PARTICIPATES_IN]->(:lCompany {id:2353462})
WHERE inter-[:WORKED_IN|PARTICIPATES_IN]->(:lDeal)<-[:PARTICIPATES_IN]-(:lCompany)<-[:WRITTEN_ABOUT]-(:lArticle {articleId:13194153})
```

The significant difference is using one of the paths as a filter in the `WHERE` clause instead of making an additional `MATCH` and an intersection operation. You may find that switching the patterns between `MATCH` and `WHERE` also affects performance according to cardinality, but I'm not certain how big a difference there would be.

#### 2) MATCH a MATCH b vs. MATCH a, b

There can be a big difference between separating your match patterns into different `MATCH` clauses as opposed to listing them separated by comma in the one `MATCH` clause. The difference is that comma separated list will consider the patterns to be parts of the same pattern, albeit perhaps a disjoint pattern, and will enforce relationship uniqueness while traversing. With the patterns in separate `MATCH` clauses, the patterns are treated individually and the same relationship can be traversed again. Perhaps you are separating out the patterns advisedly. Since you do a `DISTINCT` operation on the collection of node ids, however, you may want to revisit and make sure that distinct `MATCH` clauses is what you really want. Take a look at the following two queries on the default graph at http://console.neo4j.org

```
MATCH (n:Crew { name:"Neo" })-[:KNOWS|LOVES]->(m)
MATCH n-[:LOVES]->o
RETURN n,m,o
----
n                       m                           o
(0:Crew {name:"Neo"})   (1:Crew {name:"Morpheus"})  (2:Crew {name:"Trinity"})
(0:Crew {name:"Neo"})   (2:Crew {name:"Trinity"})   (2:Crew {name:"Trinity"})
```

and

```
MATCH (n:Crew { name:"Neo" })-[:KNOWS|LOVES]->(m), n-[:LOVES]->o
RETURN n,m,o
----
n                        m                            o
(0:Crew {name:"Neo"})    (1:Crew {name:"Morpheus"})   (2:Crew {name:"Trinity"})
```

The difference is that the first query, with separate `MATCH` clauses, is allowed to reuse the relationships matched in the first query and therefore has more matches than the second. You can read about it at [section 8.4](http://neo4j.com/docs/milestone/cypherdoc-uniqueness.html) in the manual.

The above suggested query, pulling all the matching into one `MATCH` clause, would take care of this also, if indeed it is a cause of inefficiency.

#### *) Identifiers

With the patterns expressed as in my query suggestion above most of the identifiers are no longer needed. I dropped these, not for performance but because I think it makes the query more readable, and I suppose that's also a kind of efficiency.

Comment: I have yet to digest all this, but I took your suggested query, fixed the typo where you had (:lDeal)-[:PARTICIPATES_IN]->(:lCompany {id:2353462}) instead of (:lDeal)<-[:PARTICIPATES_IN]-(:lCompany {id:2353462})  and I have am not seeing any improvement in query execution time.   Let me read through and make sure I am following all your recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

What you try is a sql-style join.

Try this instead:

```
MATCH 
  (inter)-[:WORKED_IN|PARTICIPATES_IN]->(:lDeal)<-[:PARTICIPATES_IN]-(:lCompany {id:2353462})
using index c:lCompany(id)

WITH distinct inter

MATCH   inter-[:WORKED_IN|PARTICIPATES_IN]->(:lDeal)<-[:PARTICIPATES_IN]-(:lCompany)<-[:WRITTEN_ABOUT]-(a:lArticle {articleId:13194153})
USING INDEX a:lArticle(articleId)
RETURN inter;
```

It reduces the # of intermediate results, i.e. how many distinct `inter`s you have, to reduce the amount of work subsequent query parts have to do.

It is also always interesting to see how many distinct vs. total rows you have.

please share the numbers and the plans, these 2 queries return:

```
PROFILE
MATCH 
      (inter)-[:WORKED_IN|PARTICIPATES_IN]->(deal:lDeal)<-[:PARTICIPATES_IN]-(c:lCompany {id:2353462})
using index c:lCompany(id)
RETURN count(*), count(distinct inter), count(distinct deal), count(distinct c);


PROFILE
    MATCH   inter-[:WORKED_IN|PARTICIPATES_IN]->(deal:lDeal)<-[:PARTICIPATES_IN]-(c:lCompany)<-[:WRITTEN_ABOUT]-(a:lArticle {articleId:13194153})
    USING INDEX a:lArticle(articleId)
    RETURN count(*), count(distinct inter), count(distinct deal), count(distinct a), count(distinct c);
```

Comment: Michael, I added the 2 profiles you requested to the original question.  Unfortunately, the solution you gave is taking too long to profile.

Comment: Also just added the counts which I had missed.